# Need to decide data structure to perform Set operation on Millions of strings

Tags: mysql, elasticsearch, data-structures, redis, set

What could be the best data structure to perform Set operations like (intersection, difference) on Millions of strings (each of length 50).

Usecase: Perform intersection and difference on millions of strings and this data set is different each time which changes usually once a day.

Usual Steps:

1. Add all the elements to the sets.
2. Perform Set operations (intersection and difference) on these sets.
3. Delete all Sets once we got the result.

I was thinking of using Redis but it will take more memory.

Can you please suggest will be the best data structure for this scenario like Redis, MySQL, elastic search, etc.?

Comment: Are you trying to just compare the Sets or look for the diff?

Comment: I'm performing intersection and difference on sets. @GuyKorland

Comment: Do you have enough RAM to keep all data in memory?

Comment: Yes, it usually takes more ram than usual. I was concerned that storing millions of records in one Redis key can break my code at any time @ilvar

Comment: Not in Redis, just in memory of your application. Are you running out of memory on your server?

Comment: It's not running out of memory, but yeah it consumes more memory than usual, memory increases 4 times from the normal usage. @ilvar

Comment: That's perfectly understandable. Though if you have enough RAM why do you want to use an external service? That's an additional point of failure + maintenance overhead + synchronization etc. Why not just keep it in RAM?

Comment: @ilvar I want a fallback mechanism in case Redis stops, I want to use some other better flow because if the data size increases to billions then it can go out of memory and even the server can crash.

Comment: It might be better to design your system in such a way that the underlying storage can be changed relatively easily so you have memory now and can switch to something else when (*if*) needed. It's a common mistake to introduce extra complexity (and extra overhead) early in the project and it never pays off.

Comment: I don't think MySQL or Elasticsearch or Redis will allow you to run set operations on billions of strings out of the box, it's a very specific feature. You'll have to look for algorithms and implementations tailored for massive data sets.